# vim: go to the last character of line plus one

Tags: vim

I have a problem when I use the paste command (remapped to C-V) at the end of the line.

Of course it inserts a char before the last one, and not after...
However if I want to insert one after that I have to insert a space, paste the text and delete the space.

Is there a way to make Vim go to the end of the line, plus one char so I can paste quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two paste commands in vi; `P` to paste before the cursor position and `p` to paste after the cursor position.  Make sure you are remapping `p`.

Comment: Hopefully you won't ever need to paste at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of `p`ut is to do as you require, rather than what Ctrl+V does. Maybe you could remap C-V to `"*p`.